# Method for pairwise ordering two datasets

Tags: clustering, dataset, k-means

Given two rather small but unordered multidimensional vectors/datasets (e.g sets of a handful of 3D coordinates), what is a simple method for pairwise alignment/ordering?
I've though about using clustering algorithms such as KMeans, but I am unsure how to constrain to the pairwise aspect of the problem.

Comment: What is pairwise alignment/ordering supposed to achieve? Is it to find a mapping that encodes a minimal deformation of one shape into another? Something entirely different? How is one pairwise alignment judged to be better than another?